# Print time stamp in c

Tags: c, time, time.h

I used the following code in c for time stamping.
Singapore time zone should be UTC+08. But it came out as 0000

```
time_t now;
time(&now);
char ts[sizeof "1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"];
strftime(ts, sizeof ts, "%FT%T%z", gmtime(&now));
```

The output is "2024-03-28T03:20:13+0000"
Time is also wrong. Should be 11:20 but it shows as 03:20.
How can I make changes?

Comment: [what's the difference between localtime() and gmtime() in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409025/whats-the-difference-between-localtime-and-gmtime-in-c) perhaps?

Comment: AFAICT, _your_ timezone is `EDT` (New York). You're using `gmtime`. But, `strftime` wants `localtime` as evidenced by the result being off by 4 hours (i.e. EDT is 4 hours different from GMT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using the `gmtime()` function, which converts the time to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) time zone, hence the "+0000" in your output. To get the time in the Singapore time zone (UTC+08:00), you should use the `localtime()` function instead of `gmtime()`. However, since `localtime()` adjusts for the local time zone of the system, you need to manually adjust it to Singapore time zone.

Here's how you can modify your code to get the time in the Singapore time zone:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    
    // Get the time structure in local time zone
    struct tm *local_time = localtime(&now);
    
    // Adjust for Singapore time zone (+08:00)
    local_time->tm_hour += 8;
    
    // Correct hour if it exceeds 24
    if (local_time->tm_hour >= 24) {
        local_time->tm_hour -= 24;
    }
    
    char ts[sizeof "1970-01-01T00:00:00+08:00"];
    strftime(ts, sizeof ts, "%FT%T%z", local_time);
    
    printf("%s\n", ts);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This code adjusts the hour of the time structure obtained from `localtime()` to match the Singapore time zone. Then, it formats the timestamp using `strftime()` with the "%z" format specifier to include the time zone information.

Please note that this solution assumes that the time zone offset for Singapore is always UTC+08:00, which might not be accurate during daylight saving time changes. If you need to handle daylight saving time changes, you may need to use a more sophisticated approach or a library that provides timezone handling functionality.

Comment: ChatGPT answers are banned on stack

Comment: I did notice that you commented on one of the other posts asking about the ban and that you've deleted your others.  As you've probably figured out by now, yes, use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow.  You should also have received a warning banner directly above the *"Answer"* text box when posting with this information, but apparently it's easy to miss when you are pasting from ChatGPT :-/ (not a snide remark - just reality).

Comment: I know that you can't delete this one since it was accepted, but you can Flag it and ask for a Mod to remove it because it is ChatGPT/AI-generated.  This should help you avoid any negative repercussions (e.g., a Mod warning) from the posting. Thanks!